# Why do we need scalar-by-matrix derivative?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

We all know that there are such types of derivative:

[image]

And scalar-by-matrix derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \textbf{X}}  $ is defined as follow:

\begin{pmatrix}
\partial y / \partial x_{11} & \partial y / \partial x_{21} & \ldots  &\partial y / \partial x_{p1}\\
\partial y / \partial x_{12} & \partial y / \partial x_{22} & \ldots &\partial y / \partial x_{p2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\partial y / \partial x_{1q} & \partial y / \partial x_{2q} & \ldots &\partial y / \partial x_{pq}\\
\end{pmatrix}

So, why do we need this if we can just put all variables of $y$ in vector and take scalar-by-vector derivative?

Probably, I failed to get the main idea about scalar-by-matrix derivative, can you give me some numerical example? I can't find any concrete example in any textbooks.

Comment: The strategy of flattening matrix variables into vectors often works, but it runs into trouble with matrix-specific functions like $y=\det(X)$.

Comment: If you vectorize the (scalar-by-matrix) gradient, then you may need to vectorize a number of matrices, too. For example, in order to use the standard inner product rather than the Frobenius inner product. What is gained? Once you vectorize, it's easy to forget the original dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting thing is often how our objects transform under base changes. For example, if we rotate our coordinate system by $90°$, the vector $(1,0)$ is transformed into the vector $(0,1)$. This is because the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
acts on it, the rotations matrix by $90°$. Similarly, if we want to rotate a matrix $A$ by $90^°$, we act on it like this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} A \: \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
This yields a different result that writing out our matrix $A$ as a vector and rotating that, as one easily sees (one wouldn't even know in which direction to rotate that $4$-dim. vector). What we learn from this is the following: A matrix is a matrix because it transforms like a matrix under coordinate transformations, not because it has $n \times n$ components. By this reasoning, it is clear why we should keeps this matrix form explicit when taking the derivative by matrix indices.

However, if I am honest, I can't really think of many situtation where one actually needs to derive by a matrix. Only in the theory of Lie groups and algebras, if one doesn't want to take a more abstract approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may as well ask why we need matrices at all, when we can just put all the variables in one long vector.